# zsh: exec format error: rvm

Tags: rvm, oh-my-zsh

I have `zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)` on a Mac OS 10.10.5 Yosemite

I just did a new install of RVM for my user via:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

following: https://rvm.io/rvm/install. So RVM lives in /Users/myuser/.rvm.

I added this to my ~/.zshrc:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"`.

When I run `rvm` within my oh-my-zsh shell I get (I restarted my shell)

```
zsh: exec format error: rvm
```

I have no idea how to debug this. And I cannot find anything online. I tried redoing the install with the --autodot-files flag included. Didn't help.

The results of installing RVM

```
Turning on auto dotfiles mode.
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.27.0.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.27.0/1.27.0.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Tue Mar 29 03:49:47 2016 HST using ...
gpg: Good signature from "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: ...
     Subkey fingerprint: ...
GPG verified '/Users/myuser/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.27.0.tgz'

Installing RVM to /Users/myuser/.rvm/
    Removing rvm PATH line from /Users/myuser/.mkshrc /Users/myuser/.profile /Users/myuser/.bashrc /Users/myuser/.zshrc.
    Adding rvm PATH line to /Users/myuser/.profile /Users/myuser/.mkshrc /Users/myuser/.bashrc /Users/myuser/.zshrc.
    Removing rvm loading line from /Users/myuser/.profile /Users/myuser/.bash_profile /Users/myuser/.zshrc /Users/myuser/.zlogin.
    Adding rvm loading line to /Users/myuser/.profile /Users/myuser/.bash_profile /Users/myuser/.zlogin.
Installation of RVM in /Users/myuser/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/myuser/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# hjelmeir,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

./scripts/notes: line 12: rvm_warn: command not found
./scripts/notes: line 133: __rvm_sed: command not found
./scripts/notes: line 36: rvm_error: command not found
./scripts/notes: line 220: __rvm_get_user_shell: command not found
./scripts/notes: line 254: __rvm_grep: command not found
./scripts/notes: line 255: __rvm_grep: command not found
```

I run the `source /Users/myuser/.rvm/scripts/rvm`command, then tried `rvm` with the exec format error as the result.

ADDITION:

```
file ~/.rvm/bin/rvm
/Users/myuser/.rvm/bin/rvm: empty
```

Comment: Ok, so I never figured this out and had to wipe my system clean and start fresh :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wipe my system clean and start fresh, so this one doesn't have a real answer. But I got it working and I started using rbenv.